# Как сконвертировать Object Array в Json Array?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть Object Array. Как его сконвертировать в Json Array?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е на выходе должно получиться

```
ROW_DATA = [{
        "autor": "",
         "autorznak": "A22",
        ....
    }, {
        "autor": "",
         "autorznak": "A22",
        ....
    }]
```

Comment: `ROW_DATA = obj.books`

Comment: _Есть Object Array_ - это не _Object Array_, это обычный объект

Comment: _Json Array_ - что это значит? обычный массив, или его строковое представление?

Comment: @Grundy массив в виде строки. как показано в тексте

Comment: `ROW_DATA = JSON.stringify(obj.books);`

Comment: @Radzhab, в вопросе обычный массив.